# Create two dataframes in pandas based on values in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following data

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], "b": [4, 5, 9, 5, 6, 4, 0]})
df["split_by"] = df["b"].eq(9)
```

which looks as

```
a  b  split_by
0  1  4     False
1  2  5     False
2  3  9      True
3  4  5     False
4  5  6     False
5  6  4     False
6  7  0     False
```

I would like to create two dataframes as follows:

```
   a  b  split_by
0  1  4     False
1  2  5     False
```

and

```
   a  b  split_by
2  3  9      True
3  4  5     False
4  5  6     False
5  6  4     False
6  7  0     False
```

Clearly this is based on the value in column `split_by`, but I'm not sure how to subset using this.

My approach is:

```py
split_1 = df.index < df[df["split_by"].eq(True)].index.to_list()[0]
split_2 = ~df.index.isin(split_1)

df1 = df[split_1]
df2 = df[split_2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `argmax` as:

```
true_index = df['split_by'].argmax()
df1 = df.loc[:true_index-1, :]
df2 = df.loc[true_index:, :]

print(df1)
   a  b  split_by
0  1  4     False
1  2  5     False

print(df2)
   a  b  split_by
2  3  9      True
3  4  5     False
4  5  6     False
5  6  4     False
6  7  0     False
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
i = df[df['split_by']==True].index.values[0]
df1 = df.iloc[:i]
df2 = df.iloc[i:]
```

This is assuming you have only one "True". If you have more than one "True", this code will split df into only two dataframes regardless, considering only the first "True".

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` with `cumsum` , notice if you have more then one True , this will split the dataframe to n+1 dfs (n True)

```
d={x : y for x , y in df.groupby(df.split_by.cumsum())}
d[0]
   a  b  split_by
0  1  4     False
1  2  5     False
d[1]
   a  b  split_by
2  3  9      True
3  4  5     False
4  5  6     False
5  6  4     False
6  7  0     False
```